# Java Sort Xml by element

Tags: java, xml, sorting, dom

I am trying to sort this XMl

```
<phoneBook first="JJ">
    <last>Jo</last>
    <type>Cellphone</type>
</phoneBook>
```

by the element last.

```
public static Map<String, Node> sortElements(Document doc, Map<String, Node> map, String sortBy){
        if(map == null)
            map = new HashMap<>();
        NodeList selection =doc.getElementsByTagName("phoneBook");      
        for(int i = 0; i < selection.getLength(); i++){
            Node rel = selection.item(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < rel.getChildNodes().getLength(); j++){
                Node jn = rel.getChildNodes().item(j);
                if(jn.getNodeName().equals(sortBy)){
                    map.put(jn.getNodeValue(), rel);
                }}}
        return new TreeMap<>(map);
    }
```

unfortunately one node is empty.It throws NPE!
I call the method like this inside DOM Parser!

```
SortPhoneBook.sortElements(doc, null, "last");
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put null value into the map key.

Your code:

```
map.put(jn.getNodeValue(), rel);
```

Just replace it to:

```
map.put(jn.getTextContent(), rel);
```